# Needed help in wcf service consuming

Tags: c#, wcf, binding, hosting, wcfserviceclient

I have this WCF service hosted on IIS. When I try to consume it in my client project using below code I get following exception "An error occurred while sending the request"

```
LaunchService.LaunchServiceClient launchServiceClient =
            new LaunchService.LaunchServiceClient(
            new BasicHttpBinding(),
            new EndpointAddress("http:// Service base address"));
```

If I change `BasicHttpBinding()` to `WebHttpBinding()` in above code(as in my web.config file) I get this error

> "System.TypeLoadException: 'Could not load type
>   'System.ServiceModel.WebHttpBinding' from assembly
>   'System.ServiceModel.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.'"

When using default constructor, I get this error

> "System.PlatformNotSupportedException: 'Configuration files are not 
>   supported. "
>
> LaunchService.LaunchServiceClient launchService = new
>   LaunchService.LaunchServiceClient();

I tried changing setting in web config file, but any changes in it wont make the service work.

Any help?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: I was receiving the "System.PlatformNotSupportedException: 'Configuration files are not supported." and it was due to having accidently included a .net core library in my .net framework project via nuget.  I had to edit he project file to remove it.

Answer (score -2):

I got this issue when i added a reference of .net project ('which has the service') in my core project

> solution : remove .net project and add new core project

note : some implementation must be modified when initializing the service

Comment: Please be more specific about what needs to be modified.  Simply saying "some implementation must be modified when initializing the service" is not very helpful.

Comment: it's because it depends one project to other :) @daveep

Comment: That's a 'why' not a 'what' :)